# Finding $i^{i^i}$: Review My Work

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Please let me know if my work is correct:

We know that: $i^i = e^{-\pi/2}e^{-2 \pi m}, m=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$
Thus,
$$
i^{i^i} = i^{e^{-\pi/2}\space\space\space\space e^{-2 \pi m}}\\
=e^{e^{-\pi/2}\space\space\space\space e^{-2 \pi m} \space\space\space\space\ln i}\\
=e^{e^{-\pi/2}\space\space\space\space e^{-2 \pi m} \space\space\space\space(\ln |i| + i \arg i)}\\
=e^{e^{-\pi/2}\space\space\space\space e^{-2 \pi m} \space\space\space\space(i (\pi/2)+2\pi ik)}\\
=e^{e^{-\pi/2} \space\space\space\space e^{i(-\pi^2m -4 \pi^2mk)}}
$$
for $m,k = 0,\pm1,\pm2,...$

Comment: First line has error, which carries through. Exponent should be $-2\pi im$.

Answer (score 1):

A better way.  $a=i^i=e^{-\frac{pi}{2}}$.  $x=i^a=e^{aln(i)}$, but $i=e^\frac{\pi i}{2}$, so $ln(i)=\frac{\pi i}{2}$  Net $x=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}}$

Comment: I ignored the $e^{2\pi im}=1$ factors.